# How to Perform Update and Delete operation in listview item row while Click the button in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-cursoradapter

With the help of sqlite database I am added the Cricket player name and finally it display the names in listview.

I am added the Update and delete button in CustomCursorAdapter.java.Below I am posted the Adapter code for that:

**CustomCursorAdapter.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

        TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_name);
        textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

      //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        Button updateBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.update_btn);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });  

        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                //do something

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

**single_row_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:text="Update" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_person_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Sample Data"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PersonDatabaseHelper.java:**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    // table configuration
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN = "person_pin";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
    public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonPin) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, aPersonPin);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation 

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

In that above screenshot,it shows the Update and delete button.If I click the Update button it have to show an alert dialog and edit the name of the specified listview and display it.

Then if I click the Delete button,it have to delete the appropriate listview row.

Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: You can not override the list content list in cursor adapter you have to use BaseAdapter and override listitemclick in activity.

Comment: use BaseAdapter  and when u click the update some dialog will open may be

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper it seems to be working fine with Cursor adapter.My all codes related to cursor adapter only.There will be a possibility to do with cursor adapter.

Comment: it seems to be working fine with Cursor adapter.My all codes related to cursor adapter only.There will be a possibility to do with cursor adapter @NaveenTamrakar

Comment: It will be done in onItemClickListener of listview from activity

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Nope.I never need to do it like that.Because with the help of sqlite code I am getting the listview at the end.

Comment: As i saw your code you have not deleted the row from cursor. you should call notifydatasetchanged after delete from cursor

Comment: @Naruto what is the problem with your code? your code seems ok,just put delete and update code in right place

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I didn't know how to add the Update and delete functionality in adapter.That's my problem.

Comment: Firstly take the global variable for the Cursor object. set reference of global variable with the cursor object received in the constructor. call delete function of cursor in the delete click listener

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper I tried that,but didn't working

Comment: Can you please send the code what you have updated?

Comment: you have done wrong implementation to delete the data from cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I done it on my own.But instead of using `Cursor Adapter` I am using `Base Adapter` to get the output.

I referred this [Tutorial](http://android.plan3t.com/2013/04/android-sqlite-tutorial.html).I took more time to find this tutorial.It helped me a lot.Then I change some modification for the front page and for my requirement.

[image]

I change my front page like this.Below I am showing the changes in MainActivity for that:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn_add;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    private ListView listview;

    DatabaseHelper db;
    public ArrayList<ProductModel> _productlist = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(this);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
                Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    }  

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        _productlist.clear();

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<ProductModel> product_list = db.getProudcts();

        for (int i = 0; i < product_list.size(); i++) {

            String tidno = product_list.get(i).getIdno();

            System.out.println("tidno>>>>>" + tidno);
            String tname = product_list.get(i).getProductname();
            String tprice = product_list.get(i).getProductprice();

            ProductModel _ProductModel = new ProductModel();

            _ProductModel.setIdno(tidno);
            _ProductModel.setProductname(tname);
            _ProductModel.setProductprice(tprice);

            _productlist.add(_ProductModel);
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
        db.close();

    }

    private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        public ListAdapter(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return _productlist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.txt_pname = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypname);
                viewHolder.txt_pprice = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypprice);

                viewHolder.txtidno = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypid);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.txt_pname.setText(_productlist.get(position)
                    .getProductname().trim());
            viewHolder.txt_pprice.setText(_productlist.get(position)
                    .getProductprice().trim());

            viewHolder.txtidno.setText(_productlist.get(position).getIdno()
                    .trim());

            final int temp = position;
            (convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_update))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            String _productid = String.valueOf(_productlist
                                    .get(temp).getIdno());
                            String _productname = _productlist.get(temp)
                                    .getProductname();
                            String _productprice = _productlist.get(temp)
                                    .getProductprice();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                    AddUpdateValues.class);

                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("id", _productid);
                            bundle.putString("name", _productname);
                            bundle.putString("price", _productprice);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

            (convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    MainActivity.this);
                            alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                            alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
                            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                            Log.i(">>>TEMP>>>", temp + "");
                                            Log.i(">>>getIdno>>>>>>",
                                                    _productlist.get(temp)
                                                            .getIdno().trim()
                                                            + "");
                                            System.out
                                                    .println(">>>getIdno>>>>>>"
                                                            + _productlist
                                                                    .get(temp)
                                                                    .getIdno()
                                                                    .trim());
                                            db.removeProduct(
                                                    _productlist.get(temp)
                                                            .getIdno().trim(),
                                                    "", "");

                                            MainActivity.this.onResume();

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Project Deleted...",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }  

                                    });
                            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                        }
                                    });
                            alertbox.show();
                        }
                    });
            return convertView;

        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_pname;
        TextView txt_pprice;
        TextView txtidno;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_add:
            Intent addintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddRecord.class);
            startActivity(addintent);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

I Hope this answer may be helpful to someone.

Comment: that link is brokern